# Remove .svc from REST WCF service with "?wsdl" and "/help" still enabled

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis, rest, url-rewriting

None of the prior SO questions/answers lead me to a complete REST / WCF solution that removes the SVC extension from all aspects of the service.

Specifically I'm referring to  `servicename/help` and `servicename/wsdl` ... but I know it's possible.  [Here is a working example](http://stephenpattenconsulting.com/Services/help)  of someone who is able to remove the WCF extension from the /help link.  In addition he made it impossible to call the .svc directly with the extension.  It appears that the WSDL is non existent (though I'd prefer to keep this)

How do I make my WCF REST application act more like that link?

Here is the IIS URL Rewrite that gets me part way there.  It seems kind of hokey because if I don't have the first (of two) rewrites then the web service randomly gets borked.

```
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>


    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="test1.svc" stopProcessing="true" >
          <match url="^test1.svc(.*)$"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="test1" stopProcessing="true" >
          <match url="^test1(.*)$"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/test1.svc{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: @Stephen Patten - I noticed you're a SO user.  I'll see if this mention will get you to this post...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using .Net Framework 4, based on the link you posted. If this is the case, you don't need to use .svc files, because it now integrates with [ASP.NET routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). Therefore, you can use the new [ServiceRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.serviceroute.aspx) class to add your service URLs to the ASP.NET [Route table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.aspx). For more information see the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358760.aspx).

Comment: For an implementation of this approach [see this Ron Jacob's article](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx) for how to do it.

Answer (score -2):

WCF 4 also allows you to provide alias addressing using fileless activation and Windows Activation Services. (WAS)

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="/GreetingService" service="GreetingService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Also anything that's not registered with IIS gets this error: `The extension '.t' is not registered with WCF/WF handler. Please either remove relativeAddress '~/t1.t' in 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations' from configuration file or register the corresponding extension '.t' with WCF/WF handler. Please refer to 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx' for how to register an extension in IIS.`

Comment: You may need the "process all modules" hack in .config, and/or or proper setup of your modules/handlers for static content vs. dynamic content in IIS. Check to see if the static content handler is set up to expect the folder or file to exist.